# How to fix the infinite loop error of "f = lambda x: f(x)+1" in a functional programming language?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Consider the following code in python:

f = lambda x: x

f = lambda x: f(x)+1

f(1)

Python throws an "infinite loop" error while running the last line, which is clear in the way that it interprets the second line as a recursive formula for f.

But the second line seems resonable if one substitutes the 'value' of f in the right side, and then assigns the resulting function to f (in the left).

Does there exists a straightforward way for fixing this error in python (or another language which can work with functions) via lambda calculus operations?

I asked this question just for curiosity to know much more about functional languages, but it seems to me that the answer helps to produce loop calculations on functions!

Comment: A the risk of stating the obvious: (1) Add `g = f` between those two assignments and (2) replace all occurrences of `f` in the right-hand side of the second assignment with `g`. That way, you "fix" the value of `f` by way of an intermediate variable. In a *truly* functional language, you won't run into this problem since most values are immutable, and, thus, you won't "reassign" `f`.

Comment: @Heinzi It seems that this does not work in python. Does it work in another program? (like scala?)

Comment: Works for me: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P03BViEnMTcpJVGhwkqhgisdyE/jQhVN16jQ1Dbk4iooyswr0UjTMNTU/P8fAA

Comment: What do you mean by "*fixing this error*"? Just don't write code with this mistake in it? Are you trying to create a linter that detects this kind of mistake? Are you trying to create a tool that can automatically rewrite the python code to your desired meaning?

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, you are right. But its strange for me how this works in python, and why this does not yield an infinite loop? (in this new way. f=g+1=f+1 !!!)

Comment: @Mostafa: In this context, `=` does not mean *equals*. It means "store whatever is on the right side in the variable on the left side". Some programming languages use a left-arrow instead, which makes this more explicit: `g ← f`. Thus, `g` now contains your "old" lambda and `f` the new one (compare it with `f = 2; g = f; f = 3` - now g contains 2 and f contains 3). Note that lambdas make everything more complicated because they create a "closure" and "capture variables". You can use these search terms for further research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. In Lisp/Scheme family, you can use `let*` for this purpose:

```lisp
(let* ((f (lambda (x) x))
       (f (lambda (x) (+ (f x) 1))))
  (display (f 1)))
```

Note that you'll find Scheme syntax to be much closer to lambda-calculus, aside from the prefix notation. The `let*` construct sequentially defines names, allowing the fist name to be used in the body of the second, even if you "shadow" it.

In Python, you'll have to name the functions separately, something like this:

```py
f0 = lambda x: x
f1 = lambda x: f0(x) + 1
print(f1(1))
```

If you want to study lambda-calculus, especially the untyped kind, Scheme is your best choice as most lambda-calculus constructs will map directly to it, modulo the prefix syntax. For typed lambda-calculus, a good choice would be a language like Haskell. I personally wouldn't use Python to study functional programming, as it conflates the two styles in ways that will prove to be a hindrance; though of course it's doable.

Comment: Thanks @alias for this very illuminating answer!